# Why can we subtract two terms and use this as a way to simplify the overall expression?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplacian

Our professor was doing a Laplacian transform example in class.

Original problem:

$$
y''+4y=\sin t
$$

He was working on the problem and got to this step:

$$
L^{-1}\left(L(y)\right)=L^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{s^2+1}\cdot\frac{1}{s^2+4}\right)
$$

He claimed that this is possible:

$$
(s^2+4)-(s^2+1)=3
$$
$$
\frac{(s^2+4)}{3}-\frac{(s^2+1)}{3}=1
$$

Thus:

$$
L^{-1}(L(y))=L^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{3}\cdot \frac{1}{s^2+1}\right)-L^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{3} \cdot \frac{1}{s^2+4}\right)
$$
And finally:
$$
y=\frac{\sin t}{3}-\frac{\sin2t}{6}
$$

Why does his claim work? What is the reasoning behind why that works? And is that allowed when the two expressions have more than just $2$ terms, such as $s^2-6s+9$ and $2s^2+s-1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He wrote that

$$\frac{1}{(s^2+1)(s^2+4)} = \frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{s^2+1} - \frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{s^2+4}$$

It's a classical method of partial fraction decomposition:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition